# Salesforce SOQL query: How to use SELECT with WHERE Condition

Tags: select, salesforce, where-clause, soql

For the given SOQL query, trying to optimize SOQL Query. I have two queries

**Query 1** to get userID from salesforce for the given user account

```
SELECT id From User WHERE Username = 'test@testmail.com'
```

**Query 2** for the given user ID find custom objects

```
SELECT Id,Headline__c,Description__c
FROM Incident__c
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Incident__c FROM Node_Affected__c 
        WHERE (Incident__r.Account__c = '034524000000uzurX')
        AND Incident__r.Indicator__c = false)
```

Now I want to optimize it to one query such that I dont have to make two api calls from external system. So I was trying

```
SELECT Id,Headline__c,Description__c
FROM Incident__c
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Incident__c FROM Node_Affected__c 
        WHERE (Incident__r.Account__c = null OR Incident__r.Account__c IN (SELECT id From User WHERE Username = 'test@testmail.com'))
        AND Incident__r.Indicator__c = false)
```

But I get the following error

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: 
Incident__r.Account__c IN (SELECT id From User WHERE Username = 'test@testmail.com'))
                                          ^
ERROR at Row:5:Column:87
Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported
```

Is there any better way to solve this type of problem? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the SOQL feature to follow foreign keys and follow the account__c relationship to the user table and filter on username from there, e.g.

```
SELECT Id, Headline__c, Description__c
FROM Incident__c
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Incident__c FROM Node_Affected__c 
        WHERE (Incident__r.Account__c = null OR 
               Incident__r.Account__r.Username = 'test@testmail.com')
        AND Incident__r.Indicator__c = false)
```